# Is it possible to strike-through a Label's text in Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Is it possible to apply a strike-through to a Label's text in Appcelerator? If so, how?

Comment: have a look at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AttributedString

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a Label you can use attributed string. Which offers quite some functionality.

An example for Strikethrough is this:

```
var attr = Ti.UI.createAttributedString({
    text: 'TEXT THAT NEEDS STRIKETHROUGH',
    attributes: [
        {
            type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_STRIKETHROUGH_STYLE,
            value: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_STYLE_THICK, // Ignored by Android only displays a single line
            range: [text.indexOf('hyperloop'), ('hyperloop').length]
        }
    ]
});
```

Example is taken from the [Attributed String Guide which is on the Appcelerator Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Attributed_Strings-section-37538231_AttributedStrings-Strikethrough)